# Optimizing parameters in C function for MIPs/gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, optimization, mips

I'm trying to optimize some code, and I discovered that gcc treats two uint_64 parameters differently than a struct with two uint_64's in it.   If I have:

```c
void testFn2Parm( uint64_t p1, uint64_t p2 ) {
    tp[0] = p1;
    tp[1] = p2;
}
```

it resolves to:

```
void testFn2Parm( uint64_t p1, uint64_t p2 ) {
tp[0] = p1;
1d18:       3c020000        lui     v0,0x0
1d1c:       fc440000        sd      a0,0(v0)
tp[1] = p2;
1d20:       64430000        daddiu  v1,v0,0
1d24:       03e00008        jr      ra
1d28:       fc650008        sd      a1,8(v1)
1d2c:       00000000        nop
```

where `a0` and `a1` are the values of the parameters -- no stack access.    However, if I do:

```c
struct ts {
     uint64_t    t64[2];
};

void testFnTsParm( struct ts ts ) {
    tp[0] = ts.t64[0];
    tp[1] = ts.t64[1];
}
```

which is essentially the same thing, I get:

```
void testFnTsParm( struct ts ts ) {
1d88:       dc830008        ld      v1,8(a0)
tp[0] = ts.t64[0];
1d8c:       3c020000        lui     v0,0x0
1d90:       dc840000        ld      a0,0(a0)
tp[1] = ts.t64[1];
1d94:       64450000        daddiu  a1,v0,0
1d98:       fca30008        sd      v1,8(a1)
1d9c:       03e00008        jr      ra
1da0:       fc440000        sd      a0,0(v0)
1da4:       00000000        nop
```

notice the extra ld commands.  In this case `a0` starts as the stack pointer.   I'm wondering if there's any clever ways around this, that doesn't involve rewriting all the calling functions?    (I'm using a cross-compiler for mips based on gcc 4.7)

Comment: Did you tried using `-Os` option? [You can see here that are identical](https://godbolt.org/g/ugFMeq)

Comment: Note that calling conventions are defined by the ABI, and the compiler only follows. Are those functions that need to be externally visible, or could they be static (which would allow the compiler to pick non-conforming calling conventions for them)?

Comment: @LPs: This is with `-O3`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse:  Thanks, that worked!   (on the test function, it inlined it everywhere, but on the non-test function, it created a copy that passed by parameter).

Comment: Ok, that worked for one function. Another is used across 12 files.   For that one i renamed the function to `_func`, and seprated the parameters into `uint64_t`'s. I then created a macro `func(struct ts)` that calls the `_func(ts.t64[0],ts.t64[1])`